How do I configure fzf to have the search input on top, while having the preview window bottom?
How do I configure fzf to have the search input on top, while having the preview window on the bottom?
I managed to set the preview window to be on the bottom by:
let g:fzf_preview_window = 'down:40%'

How I put the fzf input line to the top?
This is the result:

Note: I also managed to set the layout to be reverted which puts the input line on top but then the preview didn't work... I didn't manage to integrate the two together.

The commands are specified in this location:
https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/blob/556f45e79ae5e3970054fee4c4373472604a1b4e/plugin/fzf.vim#L63
By passing the '--layout=reverse' option to the fzf#vim#with_preview function we can customise all the search functions to have input on top.
Example:
Grep Search:
command! -bang -nargs=* Rg
    \ call fzf#vim#grep("rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case -- ".fzf#shellescape(<q-args>), fzf#vim#with_preview({'options': ['--layout=reverse', '--info=inline']}), <bang>0)'


File name search:
command! -bang -nargs=? -complete=dir Files
    \ call fzf#vim#files(<q-args>, fzf#vim#with_preview({'options': ['--layout=reverse', '--info=inline']}), <bang>0)

Then by setting the global for the preview window to be on the bottom We can amend the preview to be on the bottom.
let g:fzf_preview_window = ['down,50%']
This way We can customize the search to have the input on top and preview on bottom ;)
